# Why limit of some function to variable power is limit of the function to the power of limit of the variable.

Tags: limits

Why is the limit of some function to a variable power the limit of the function to the power of the limit of the variable ?

$$\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}(f(x))^x = \lim\limits_{x\to x_0} f(x)^{\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} x} $$

Where function $f(x)$ is continuous and $x$ belongs to reals.

Comment: Is $f$ continuous on all $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: Yes, i'm asking because our proffesor gave us an example like:
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}(cosx)^{\frac{1}{x}} = \lim\limits_{x\to 0}(cos x)^{\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}}$$

And i don't understand the principle that he uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proposition**:

> Assume that $f>0$, and $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ exists and is positive, then
>   \begin{equation*}
> \lim_{x\to x_0}(f(x))^x=\Bigl(\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)\Bigr)^{\lim_{x\to x_0}x}
> \end{equation*}

**Proof:** 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to x_0}(f(x))^x
&=\lim_{x\to x_0}\exp(x\log f(x))\\
&=\exp\Bigl(\lim_{x\to x_0} (x\log f(x))\Bigr)\quad\text{The continuity of $\exp(x)$}\\
&=\exp\Bigl(\bigl(\lim_{x\to x_0}x\bigr)\bigl(\lim_{x\to x_0}\log f(x)\bigr)\Bigr)\quad\text{The product rule for limits}\\
&=\exp\Bigl(\bigl(\lim_{x\to x_0}x\bigr)\bigl(\log\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)\bigr)\Bigr)\quad\text{The continuity of $\log(x)$}\\
&=\Bigl(\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)\Bigr)^{\lim_{x\to x_0}x}
\end{align*}

Comment: If people are going to write things like $$\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}(f(x))^x = \lim\limits_{x\to x_0} f(x)^{\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} x}$$ then it becomes doubly important that $0^0$ is undefined.

Comment: You are right! I need more conditions.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer for your question. But I think, I can solve your limit using your professor's hint. $$(\cos x)^
{\frac{1}{x}}=\Big(1-\sin^2\frac{x}{2}\Big)^{\frac{2}{x}}=\Big(1-\sin\frac{x}{2}\Big)^{\frac{2}{x}}\Big(1+\sin\frac{x}{2}\Big)^{\frac{2}{x}}$$ $$(\cos x)^
{\frac{1}{x}}=\Big(1-\dfrac{1}{\csc\dfrac{x}{2}}\Big)^{\csc\dfrac{x}{2}\Big(\dfrac{\sin\dfrac{x}{2}}{\dfrac{x}{2}}\Big)}\Big(1+\dfrac{1}{\csc\dfrac{x}{2}}\Big)^{\csc\dfrac{x}{2}\Big(\dfrac{\sin\dfrac{x}{2}}{\dfrac{x}{2}}\Big)}\to e^{-1}\times e=1$$ as $x\to 0.$